# Could not find what's wrong in sql set values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL.

```
$sql_shells = "UPDATE `shells` SET `situation` = 'sold'  WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'";
$conn->query($sql_shells);
```

I updated the rows with column named `buytime` and another one called `buyer` so it would be like this:

```
$sql_shells = "UPDATE `shells` SET `buyer`= " . $buyer . ", `buytime`= " . $trn_date . " , `situation` = 'sold'  WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'";
$conn->query($sql_shells);
```

It's not updating.

```
`$trn_date = $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

and

```
$buyer = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Error log is empty.

Another SQL update doesn't have constant values and works fine

```
$sql_users  = "UPDATE `users` SET `amount`= " . $newAmount . ", `gain`= " . $newgain . "   WHERE `username` = '" . $buyer . "'";
```

I tried echoing the SQL query that's not working, this is what I get [when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD62P.png).

Comment: You should quote and escape the values in the query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: i tell you it was updating before i added my modification

Comment: Or better yet, you should use parameterization so that all of the issues like sql injection, proper quoting, proper escaping, and all of their pitfalls can be avoided.

Comment: As for doing this by concatenating like you are doing you will need to add double quotes around your date like `buytime= \"" . $trn_date . "\"`  Don't though; use mysqli parameter binding or PDO so you don't have to worry about this stuff and you protect your app from sql injection.

Comment: @RanaMontana what you posted above has the updated value in quotes. The second query does not. It doesn't escape or sanitize the value either.

Comment: print your `sql_shells` variable and see  the update query string first. Hope it will help you out easily what you mess up?

Comment: done , check the picture , it doesn't miss anything wow

Comment: Can I ask why you don't do this? `$sql_shells = "UPDATE shells SET buyer = '$buyer', buytime = '$trn_date', situation = 'sold'  WHERE id = '$id'";`?

Comment: lol give this dude a medal , thanks @JeanPaul98, actually a friend told me it helps to avoid sql injections

Comment: Yea the query I posted is not ideal, so I would look into using prepared statements @RanaMontana

Comment: It 100% won't help with SQL injection. You REALLY need to properly bind your values with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) It's super simple and you can avoid so much of the issues you are have already ran into.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 I was about to sarcastically remark that "It protects against SQL injection attacks 50% better." and then I read OPs comment and now I am sad that this was actually the truth :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove ` caracter  and i think buytime and buyer  should add ' caracter and remove it from id if is int type:

```
 $sql_shells = "UPDATE shells SET buyer= '" . $buyer . "', buytime= '" . $trn_date . "' , situation = 'sold'  WHERE id = " . $id ;
        $conn->query($sql_shells);
```